# Combining document.load + blur

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following javascript to determine whether a copyright is properly formatted:

```
    var copyright = $('#copyright')
    var copyright_text = copyright[0].value
    if (copyright_text.length > 0) {
        var containsYear = /\d{4}/.test(copyright_text);

        if (containsYear == false) {
            copyright.css({
               'background-color': 'rgba(230, 89, 78, 0.07)',
            });
            copyright.parent().append(
               '<div class="explanatory caution">CAUTION: Make sure this copyright contains a year.</div>'
            );

        };
    };
```

How would I apply this same logic to `.blur()` as well as the normal page load above without copy and pasting all the code from above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.trigger` to trigger the callback after you add it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#copyright').blur(function() {
        var copyright = $('#copyright')
        var copyright_text = copyright[0].value
        if (copyright_text.length > 0) {
            var containsYear = /\d{4}/.test(copyright_text);

            if (containsYear == false) {
                copyright.css({
                   'background-color': 'rgba(230, 89, 78, 0.07)',
                });
                copyright.parent().append(
                   '<div class="explanatory caution">CAUTION: Make sure this copyright contains a year.</div>'
                );

            };
        };
    }).trigger('blur');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the code you have in a function. Call it when the events you are interested in occur:

```
$(document).load(function(){
    formatCopyright();

    $(<the-selector>).blur(function({
        formatCopyright();
    });

    function formatCopyright({
        // the code from your question goes here
    });
});
```